# Converting timestamp to seconds in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe containing timestamps as follows:

```
Timestamp, Position, Speed

1662189653, 53, 20
1662189669, 34, 12
1662189688, 21, 19
```

I would like to convert this timestamp to a value in seconds, and print this in a list of seconds. How do I select each timestamp in the dataframe and convert this into seconds?

I am aware of the datetime module and have tried it using the following loop:

```
time = []

for time in t:

    dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
    print (dt_object)
    dt = datetime(dt_object)
    epoch_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
    delta = (dt - epoch_time)
    time.append(delta)
```

Which raises the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

Comment: Use `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')`

Comment: Thanks, this gets me the result in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss however,  but I require the whole result in seconds, how would I do this?

Comment: not understand, `1662189653` is already in seconds, why convert to same number?

Comment: I misunderstood that timestamp is already in seconds, thanks, this solves the problem!

Comment: What is expected ouput from sample data in question? In another words what 3 values should be in list `time` ?

Comment: The time in seconds, but with a different epoch starting time, I managed to fix this now

Comment: check my last comment